# accessing HSQLDB table from JUnit not possible

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I have the problem that my unit tests fails due to the fact that I can simply not access a table which has just been created before.

From the output of the console I can see that the following Hibernate commands are executed.

```
Hibernate: alter table Server_Node drop constraint FK3621657E1249AF15
Hibernate: alter table Server_Node drop constraint FK3621657E2528B004
Hibernate: drop table EmailAccountSettings if exists
Hibernate: drop table Node if exists
Hibernate: drop table Server if exists
Hibernate: drop table Server_Node if exists
Hibernate: create table EmailAccountSettings (id varchar(255) generated by default as identity (start with 1), description varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Node (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), name varchar(255), primary key (id), unique (name))
Hibernate: create table Server (id integer generated by default as identity (start with 1), name varchar(255), primary key (id), unique (name))
Hibernate: create table Server_Node (Server_id integer not null, nodes_id bigint not null, primary key (Server_id, nodes_id))
Hibernate: alter table Server_Node add constraint FK3621657E1249AF15 foreign key (nodes_id) references Node
Hibernate: alter table Server_Node add constraint FK3621657E2528B004 foreign key (Server_id) references Server
Hibernate: insert into Server (id, name) values (default, ?)
```

As you can see values get inserted into the table `Server`. But the next test case is trying to insert something into table `EmailAccountSettings` which is causing the following error.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: user lacks privilege or object not found: EMAILACCOUNTSETTINGS
  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377)
  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
  at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:273)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  ...
```

Any idea what is wrong with the table `EmailAccountSettings`?

I'm using Spring + Hibernate + HSQLDB + JUnit just to give an overview over the components involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the reason for this problem. Looking again at the table creation statement all of a sudden the light came on.

```
Hibernate: create table EmailAccountSettings (id varchar(255) generated by default as identity (start with 1), description varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

It is not possible to create an identity column with datatype `varchar`. Therefore the statement was not successful. But this is not visible in the console when running the test.

After changing the datatype in the entity everything works as expected.